# QML "QtQuick.PrivateWidgets" plugin "widgetsplugin" not found

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qtdeclarative

I have developed my Qt application by using shared Qt libraries.

After transition to static Qt libraries `CONFIG += static`, My app crashes and I see in log

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
>
> qrc:/main.qml:907 Type MessageDialog unavailable
>
> qrc:/QtQuick/Dialogs/WidgetMessageDialog.qml:42 module "QtQuick.PrivateWidgets" plugin "widgetsplugin" not found

Problem part of qml looks like:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

ApplicationWindow {

    ...

    MessageDialog {
        id: emailSuccessDialog

        title: qsTr("Done")
        text: qsTr("Email has been sent successfully")
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- What is the `QtQuick.PrivateWidgets` plugin?
- How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just forgot to perform `make module-qtquickcontrols` in terminal

Full build command looks:

```
OPENSSL_LIBS='-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lssl -lcrypto' 

./configure -developer-build -static -opensource -confirm-license \
-nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake tools -openssl-linked

make
make module-qtquickcontrols
```